# How to translation "Invalid credentials." error in FOSUserBundle symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have this part of code in login.html.twig page

I want to translate error message "Invalid credentials."

```
 {% if error %}
     <div style="color:red">
         {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
     </div>
 {% endif %}
```

now, i'm trying to translat in messages.en.yml or in FOSUserBundle.en.yml and nothing happen. (using symfony3)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After looking for a while, I found it can help

I looked for where the message came fromץץ
and i found that this message "Invalid credentials." coming from this path.

```
vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Resources\translations\security.en.xlf
```

so i copeid the file **security.en.xlf** into **app\Resources\translations**
and made some change to the part i wanted to translate

```
<trans-unit id="4">
    <source>Invalid credentials.</source>
    <target>Username/password doesn't match</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Answer (score 1):

Btw, in my case, I just uncomment the following line in config.yml :

```
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
```

And my locale was set to "fr"

```
parameters:
    locale: fr
```

Answer (score 0):

## Symfony 4.4/5/6+

Change `fr` by the locale you want to make default:

```yaml
# config/packages/translation.yaml
framework:
    default_locale: fr
```

*Source : https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html*